# How to remove duplicate in Nautilus devices list?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

Nautilus shows a drive twice under "devices" when logged in the main account. Only one of these actually works.

When I launch Nautilus as root the drive is shown only once. How do I reset nautilus to the default settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem from another thread. The problem lies with the fstab entry of the drive.

Strangely enough, if the drive is mounted with UUID= it is shown twice in the devices list. Simply changing FSTAB to `/dev/sda*` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the nautilus to default setting by removing the nautilus config file found on your home dir

```
#rm -R ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus
```